# Check if a rectangle is near another rectangle

Tags: java, coordinates, graphics2d

I have a my rectangle.
The application generates another rectangle.
It can be more smaller or larger than my rectangle.
How can I tell when its rect near of the mine using their X, Y, Weight and Hight?? I do not want to know if is into my rectangle.

Comment: please define "near"

Comment: Perhaps try the algorithm from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978323/how-to-calculate-distance-between-two-rectangles-context-a-game-in-lua

Comment: The generated rectangle should not be inside. It may be slightly over or higher or wide. but not very other than!

Comment: You are being not exact enough. Please define "slightly". A distance of 1000000 pixels is "near" or not?

Answer (score 0):

Draw 1 or more non-visible shapes that are relative to your rectangle's position that fit your definition of "near", then check to see if these shape(s) intersect with the application-generated rectangle in question.

For example, one way you might implement this is drawing a non-visible rectangle that surrounds your rectangle, then checking to see if the surrounding rectangle intersects with the application-generated rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!
I have calculated the middle point of my rectangle.
If the rectangle generated have into the point, is near!

Comment: If the rectangle generated have the middle point into its area, is near!*

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Math formula to calculate the distance between two points like this:

```
double getDistance(int x, int y, int x2, int y2) {
  double distance;
  distance = Math.sqrt( Math.pow( Math.abs(x2 - x) , 2 ) + Math.pow( Math.abs(y2 - y) , 2 ) );
  return distance;   
}
```

Comment: Yes, but he can use this also to calculate the distance between centers or some other two points of the rectangles he decide.

Comment: I admit, your approach may be a part of the solution, but your answer does not solve his problem, at all. You should at least propose an algorithm that computes the distance between rectangles.

Comment: The [Point2D.distance method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html#distance-double-double-double-double-) already does this.